# Android Login with php/ mysql not working

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, authentication

i am new to android development, and i have here some codes i built to have a log-in functionality in my mobile app. I am trying to compare the value of the inputted data in my input text into mysql database, but it seems i am not getting the point, i really don't know if my codes is leading me into something, or it's just nonsense, can you guys help me here? By the way, i don't get any errors, just no results after clicking the button.

This are my codes:

**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Edit Text
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);

        // Create button
        Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        // button click event
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CheckLogin().execute();
            }
        });     
    }

    class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Logging in..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String eadd = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/TheCalling/log_in.php");


            try {
                nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eadd", eadd));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200){
                    entity = response.getEntity();

                    if(entity != null){

                        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));

                        String inputEmail = jsonResponse.getString("eadd");
                        String inputPassword = jsonResponse.getString("password");

                        if(eadd.equals(inputEmail) && password.equals(inputPassword)){

                            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("logindetails", 0);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor spedit = sp.edit();

                            spedit.putString("eadd", eadd);
                            spedit.putString("password", password);

                            spedit.commit();
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SUCCESS!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid login details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                   
                        }

                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

**

this is my php file:

**

```
<?php

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_password = "";
$db_name = "sample_login";
$response = array();

    $db_connect = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password) or die(mysql_error());
    $db = mysql_select_db($db_name);
    $eadd = $_POST['eadd'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE eadd = '$eadd' and password = '$password'");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Login succes";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);   
}
?>
```

**

Comment: make sure u have added Internet permission in manifast

Comment: Can we see the `log_in.php` file

Comment: PHP file posted, thanks.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Android developer but here is what i have to say.

1. The php file is all fine. The only thing is that, you are not returning the email and password, which you seem to be accessing in the android file. Here:

   InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
      JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));
      String inputEmail = jsonResponse.getString("eadd");
      String inputPassword = jsonResponse.getString("password");
2. The mysql_query() returns a resource on success if the query is correct, or FALSE on error.
   You need to check mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 for a valid match. refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Remember

```
if ($result) {
}
```

will always be true unless your query is wrong.

Comment: can you please share some feedback on the above?

Answer (score 0):

1) Can you post method 'convertStreamToString'?

2) Did you check if

```
  echo json_encode($response);
```

return correct value and doesn't return null?